# How can I exactly know which object caused my crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, crash

I have this crash which happens randomly in my app. I have many objectAtIndex in my code, how can I know the name of the array which caused he crash?

[image]

Is there a fast way to read the hexadecimal numbers?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can figure out where the crash happens by setting exception breakpoint in your breakpoint navigator.
[image: Exception BreakPoint Setup 1]

[image]

Now enable the breakpoints and run your code. Now It stops at the step where the crash happens.